# how to use express-session with Zod's TypedRequest

Tags: typescript, session, zod

i have a controller method looking like this:

```
export async function sign_up(req: TypedRequestBody<typeof UsersSignUpBody>, res: Response<MyResponse<User>>): Promise<Response> {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const user = await createUser({name, password}); ///prisma used here

    return res.json({
        attributes: user,
        dataType: 'users'
    });
}
```

i would like to use `express-session` in my project to handle authentication however it looks as if zods TypedRequest didnt have `session` method even after installing and configuring `express-session`
Are there any different libs/patterns to access session while simultaneously being able to validate input using `zod`'s `TypedRequest` or `TypedRequestBody?`